# Показать или скрыть элемент с привязкой к кэш-памяти браузера

Tags: javascript

Приветствую. Простой скрипт показать/скрыть элемент имеется.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#link').click(function(){  
   $('#div').toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link">Кнопка</a>
<div id="div">Тут содержимое</div>
```

Есть ли способ запомнить результат нажатия в кеш-памяти браузера, чтоб при переходе на другие страницы выбранный блок был закрыт или открыт?

Благодарю, за любую помощь.

Comment: куки, localstorage

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Все сделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работающее решение: http://codepen.io/pen/QEBORm

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleBlock()">Скрыть / показать</a>
<div id="div">Текст</div>
```

и сам скрипт:

```
(function() {
    var toggle = function(element, show) {
        element.style.display = show ? 'block' : 'none';
    };
    var block = document.getElementById('div');
    var visible = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('visible') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visible')) : true;
    toggle(block, visible);
    window.toggleBlock = function() {
        toggle(block, visible = !visible);
        localStorage.setItem('visible', visible);
    };
})();
```

Если вдруг кому-то потребуется решение с добавлением класса к кнопке, есть второе решение: http://codepen.io/pen/xOJYbd

HTML:

```
<a id="showhide" class="hide active" href="javascript:void(0);">список</a>
<div id="showhideblock">
text
</div>
```

и скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showhide').click(function () {
        $('#showhideblock').slideToggle(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('display', $('#showhideblock').is(':hidden'));
        });
    });
    var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
    if (block == 'true') {
        $('#showhideblock').hide();
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showhide').click(function () {
        $('#showhide').toggleClass('active');
    });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if(!$('#showhideblock').is(':hidden'))
    {
        console.log('visible');
        $('#showhide').addClass('active');
    } else if(!$('#banner').is(':visible')){
        $('#showhide').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```